# Query for specific words in Firebase Database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to make a query that looks for a certain word in a child value. For example, if I had three values that were "it is very big", "it is really big" and "it is very cool" how could I write a query that returns only the values containing the word "very"?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We are a question-and-answer site. Please explain what you have tried so far and why it hasn't worked. Also have a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Firebase Realtime Database doesn't have the ability to perform full text searches.  You'll need to augment RTDB with some other search engine (such as Algolia) that contains the same data.